# WKWebView local file in iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cross-domain, wkwebview

I've an WKWebView whose load a local html file named 'start.html'.
Inside this file, i load an other local document in iframe.

But i'm not allowed to use js from start.html on iframe content and iframe content not allowed to load js file.

Before WKWebView i've use UIWebView but i'm forced to migrate to improve performance

In UIWebView i never had any problems with the crossdomain security.

When i add attribute `sandbox='allow-same-origin'` on iframe, i can successfully execute js code from start.html like this

```
$("#frame")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('password_field')[0].value = password_field
```

but js code and http requests inside iframe (file loaded in iframe is a js player) is not allowed to run, i get theses errors :

```
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

What is the difference between UIWebVIew and WKWebView.
Is there a solution to allow js code and http requests inside iframe ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Khorwin, could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`WKWebView` is only allowed to read local content stored in the directory provided by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`.

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281889/loading-local-images-into-wkwebview/46395862#answer-46395862) for more details.