# Loading local images into WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to get WKWebView to display locally downloaded images in a `WKWebView`. The webview normally displays HTML, which is retrieved remotely. The contents of the HTML can sometimes contain remote links to images. My app parses the HTML and looks for these HTML tags, downloads the file it is referencing and subsequently replaces the remote link with a local one.

Normally speaking, this wouldn't be very difficult but the images aren't being displayed, presumably due to the images and the local HTML files for the webview being in two separate directories (the documents directory and the app bundle directory respectively). 
I've seen people suggest moving the download destination of the images to the same directory as where the HTML files are but this isn't an option for me as I don't want to start mixing up files downloaded by the user with local assets.

What would be my best course of action here?

Comment: Are the images being displayed by themselves or in the context of a downloaded page? Both instances require different solutions.

Comment: @Wes It's the latter.

Comment: Ok, I've run into this same issue before. Ideally, you want to make sure the directory that contains the HTML and the directory that contains the images both have a common ancestor directory. Secondly, make sure that your img ref urls in the HTML file reflect the native file paths that you have constructed after downloading. Lastly, when you load the html page, make sure you use `loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)` where the directory to allow access to is the common root directory the HTML and images share.

Comment: @Wes Isn't this kind of the situation I'm trying to avoid, like how I described in the OP? Because this would involve either storing my app assets (my javascript files, which get fed the data I retrieve remotely) in the documents folder or saving the downloaded files to the app's bundle (is this even possible?). Either way, I'd be mixing app resources with user data which seems really messy.

Comment: Please see my answer for a more extensive solution.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I've found a workaround. Instead of locally storing the images and referencing them in the HTML files, I'm now instead converting the images to Base64 and then adding them to the HTML. It's not ideal but it gets the job done. I'm going to leave this question open in case someone ever manages to find an actual solution.

Comment: After much searching on SO and elsewhere, this is what I have ended up doing as well. Works nicely but isn't ideal.

Comment: It seems there is a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58385398/how-to-intercept-a-wkwebview-request-to-detect-which-local-resource-files-css

Comment: @Anubis - I tried converting image to Base64 and adding it. But it is not showing on WKWebview. Is there something I am missing?
    NSString *base64Str = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *js =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('image').src='data:image/png;base64,%@';", base64Str];
    [self.wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score 3):

To display cached HTML referencing cached resources in a `WKWebView`:

1. For each of the resources within your HTML content string, cache it into the directory as provided by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. So an image tag like:

   `...<img src='https://www.myimage.com/example_image.png'/>...`

   should be cached and replaced into something like this:

   `...<img src='/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/527CF4FC-9319-4DFF-AB55-9E276890F5DC/tmp/example_image.png'/>...`
2. Now cache the HTML content string with the replaced resource URLs. It must also be cached in the directory provided by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. One difference here is that it must be cached (and later referenced) using the `file://` protocol as a restriction of caching the string using `NSData` (see sample code).

   For example `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/527CF4FC-9319-4DFF-AB55-9E276890F5DC/tmp/my_html_content_string.html`

A few things to point out:

- You cannot load the HTML as a raw string (`loadHTMLString:baseURL:`).
- You cannot reference the cached resource within your HTML string using the `file://` protocol. That may work in a `UIWebView`, but will not work in the `WKWebView`.

Objective-C

```
// To cache the HTML string:
NSString *HTML = <HTML CONTENT WITH CACHED RESOURCES>;
NSData *data = [HTML dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[data writeToURL: cachedHTMLURL atomically: YES];

// To load the store HTML file:
[myWKWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: cachedHTMLURL]]; // (file://.../tmp/my_html_content_string.html)
```

Swift

```
// To cache the HTML string:
let HTML = <HTML CONTENT WITH CACHED RESOURCES>
let data = HTML.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
do {
    try data.write(to: cachedHTMLURL, options: .atomic)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// To load the store HTML file:
myWKWebView.load(URLRequest(url: cachedHTMLURL)) // (file://.../tmp/my_html_content_string.html)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with WKWebView as it can not load both html strings and images at the same time for security purposes. I switched to UIWebView, which is deprecated, but I was able to load both html strings and referenced images at the same time.

Comment: It is no longer a solution as Apple is about to stop accepting app submission (and app updates) which uses UIWebView https://stackoverflow.com/a/61959030/3936644

Answer (score 2):

I developed a definitive solution for the company I work for. But it relies on the html / javascript side. Anywhere inside your html code where you will reference to a local image `<img src="..."/>` you should set this `"src"` dynamically, and it will work seamlessly.

```
function getLocalURL(path) {
    let origin = window.location.origin
    if (origin == "file://") {
        return origin + window.location.pathname.replace("/index.html","") + path
    }
    return path
}
```

You should, clearly, rename index.html to whatever is your main .htm(l) filename :)

**Usage**:

```
getLocalURL("/local_images/location_icon.png")
```

Will return a WKWebView working path for the referenced local image path:

`"file:///Users/arthurdapaz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5073AF19-26A0-460E-BC82-E89100B8E1AB/data/Containers/Data/Application/2B099343-0BF5-4849-B1C2-2512377A9772/Documents/distDriver/local_images/location_icon.png"`

Comment: It didn`t work for my MacOS WKWebview issue, any ideas?

Comment: It didn't work for me neither, I tried on iphone simulator and real device...

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to providing files is using the following setup:

- create a `WKWebViewConfiguration`
- call `setURLSchemeHandler:forURLScheme:` and provide a custom scheme handler for a custom scheme like `foo://`
- instantiate a `WKWebView` using this configuration. You cannot assign a custom configuration to a `nib`-based WKWebView, so you may need to create a custom-view in the `nib` and add the WKWebView as subview.
- load your html via URLs that have a custom scheme like `foo://` instead of `http://`
- as files are referred inside html mostly via relative URLs, like `images/foo.jpg`, the resulting URL will still be `foo://yadayada/images/foo.jpg` which means your handler is called for every single resource

That way it is easily possible to either provide in-memory files as resources into a WKWebView or you provide your own.

It may sound complicated but the custom scheme handler is actually easy to implement.