# Load UIImage into a WebView Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift4

Rather than loading a `WebView` from a `URL` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: imageUrl.urlString)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)

}

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    view = webView
}
```

How can I load a `UIImage` onto the `WebView` in `Swift 4`?

Comment: May we know the purpose behind that ? Is that for showing a placeholder image when content of webView is not available or is there something else ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281889/loading-local-images-into-wkwebview/46395862

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading local images into WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281889/loading-local-images-into-wkwebview)

Comment: Good job rishi. This is swift 4 i am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Something like this.

```
let html = "<html><img src=\"datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/YourImage.png\"/> </html>"

//Save this html in `DocumentDirectory`
let saveHTML = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("temp.html")

try? html.data(using: .utf8)!.write(to: saveHTML)

//Now load this `temp.html` file in webView
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: saveHTML))
```